# Flask - Change status message along with status code

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am looking for a way to change the status code message, not only the status code. Let me elaborate:

```
@app.route('/stat_code')
def stat():
    return "test", 201
```

and I cURL:
`< HTTP/1.0 201 CREATED`

What I am trying to achieve here is to change the status code message to say:

`< HTTP/1.0 201 CUSTOM MESSAGE`

I noticed a class `flask_api.status.HTTP_201_CREATED` but that is just an int. How to achieve this custom message after status code?

NOTE:
I am ok if this some RFC violation, it's only for some internal testing.

Comment: I don't think that can be changed. This message is printed by curl, not by your code. And they are set by a RFC.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the info.